# How do I start a MEAN stack project in Webstorm

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, webstorm, mean-stack

I am new to WebStorm and I want to do a project using the MEAN stack.

When I create a new project I have several hypothesis, two of them been:

- Node.js Express App
- AngularJS

Since the MEAN stack has Node, Express and Angular, which one I should choose?

How do I add the MongoDB support?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need check a tutotial for understand that, I will make a recomendation, it helped me a lot for understand the MEAN stack

https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular

I hope that this tutorial help you with the answers that you have.

and about that which type use in webstorm you can select anyone, because after that you can install the plugins that you need.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/using-angularjs.html#installManually

Answer (score 0):

Just start with the creation on new project with the *file -> new ->project*. It supports by default all of these and if you want to include any framework like Angular.js and Node.js just go to file -> setting -> *language* and *framework -> javascript -> libraries*. Thats all you need to do.

Main application is by default supported by WebStorm. You just have to provide the relevant library,